# Run cmd command using python (Stop/Start a service)

Tags: python, testing

So, i would like to know if someone knows how to stop/start service using python, IIS (W3SVC - service name).

I tried to do it several times unfortunnatly nothing worked (tried it with subprocess, create function with os to launch cmd, tried to connect as an admin ...). So here is the closest one that i could get :

```
# stop the service
args = ['sc', 'stop', 'W3SVC']
subprocess.run(args)
# start the service
args[1] = 'start'
subprocess.run(args)
```

But it returns access denied :

```
[SC] OpenService échec(s) 5 

[SC] StartService: OpenService échec(s) 5
```

It is in French, échec(s) means failure.

I am using it to automatize a test with selenium, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: How is the question related to [tag:selenium]?

Comment: It is not related to selenium, I said that just to specify what it was for

Comment: Are you able to run those commands successfully from the command prompt?

Comment: It work only if i launch cmd as admin, then write 'net stop W3SVC ' it stops the service but i have no idea how to do it with python

Comment: Does it work (in `cmd`) if you run `sc stop W3SVC` as admin? Have you tried using `runas` to run the command as admin from an un-elevated `cmd` prompt?

Comment: Oh , sc stop W3SVC doesn't work as admin. Yeah I tried to runas but it doesn't work either, asks about the password then it does nothing, or just launch cmd as admin but no stop happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, and forgot to add it here so, I just made a batch file which always start as an administrator, then used os.startfile(myBatchFile) to launch it, if you want to automate it you'll have to update the UAC to the lowest.